# how to get result if value is comma seperated in like codition

Tags: sql-server

I am trying following query but not getting any results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM InternationalPropertyLocals  
WHERE PropertyName LIKE '%Chatham,MA%'
```

But if I try the below query I get the expected result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM InternationalPropertyLocals 
WHERE PropertyName = 'Chatham, NY'
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing whitespace after the comma?

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM InternationalPropertyLocals WHERE PropertyName like '%Chatham, MA%'
```

If you know the exact PropertyName you are looking for then I would avoid using `LIKE` as `=` describes your intentions better, not to mention performance concerns.